# Limitar resultados do banco de dados?

Tags: php, sql

Continuando com as vídeos aula, me deparei com um método de exibir dados do banco de dados um pouco diferente, no vídeo é usado:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM comentarios ORDER BY data DESC');
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// e depois um do while para repetir a impressão:
do
{
echo $row['coluna0'];
echo $row['coluna1'];
echo $row['coluna2'];
}while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Mas tive problema ao implementar esse código e coloquei o seguinte:

```
echo '<table>';
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM comentarios ORDER BY data DESC');
 while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) != NULL)
 {
     echo "<tr> <td><b>Nome</b></td>";
     echo '<td>' . $row['nome'] . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     echo "<tr> <td><b>Email</b></td>";
     echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     echo "<tr> <td><b>Data</b></td>";
     echo '<td>' . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['data'])) . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     echo "<tr> <td><b>Mensagem</b></td>";
     echo '<td>' . $row['msg'] . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
 }
 mysqli_free_result($result);
 echo '</table>';
```

Aqui não tive muito problema com ele, só não consigo dar um `<br/>` entre os dados para separar e queria saber como limito o resultado, exemplo, exibir apenas os 3 primeiros registros.

Comment: "dar um `<br/>` entre os dados", você quer dizer deixar espaço entre as linhas da tabela?

Comment: Sim, um espaço somente depois da linha Mensagem da tabela (que é a última linha de um registro, tentei colocando o br ali depois do ultimo /tr porém não deu, fazendo assim ele só dá espaço antes do primeiro registro.

Comment: Para isso o melhor é fazeres uma tabela para cada linha, mas não tem grande lógica...

Comment: @JorgeB. deu certo com uma tabela para cada registro, apenas colocando `<table>` e `</table>` dentro do `while`, e depois disso pude usar o br, etc, obrigado.

Comment: Veja essa resposta sobre [como adicionar espaço entre linhas de uma tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53220/como-adicionar-espa%C3%A7amento-nas-linhas-de-uma-tabela)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para limitar o número de resultados podes usar o LIMIT do MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM comentarios ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenta usar a Clausula LIMIT ficaria assim

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM comentarios ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 3');
```